# I load a trained model, the loss is quite large

Tags: model, pytorch

I have trained a translation model:

- When  `step % 1000 == 0`, I evaluate the loss on validation.
- If the loss is small，I save the state.
- When I finish training, I load the model and the loss is quite large.

  ```
      if step % 1000 ==0:
          model.eval()
          val_loss = eval(model,val_loader)
          print("epoch:",epoch,"step:",step,"loss:",loss,"val_loss:",val_loss)

          if val_loss.item() < best_loss:
              best_loss = val_loss.item()
              best_epoch = epoch
              torch.save(model.state_dict(),'best_1.m')
  ```

when I finish the training, the loss is about 0.665 but when I load the same model the loss is about 300.

```
model.load_state_dict(torch.load('best_1.m'))
model.eval()
val_loss = eval(model,val_loader)
print('val_loss:',val_loss)
```

Comment: It will be difficult to help without seeing your eval function definition.

Comment: Are you re-instantiating the model before `model.load_state_dict(torch.load('best_1.m'))` ?